# HTML5 Canvas rotate an image with top and left position

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm developing a photoshop like and right now I'm doing the export and I have a problem with rotation.
Basically my project look like this in browser :

[image: Browser interface]
And I'm trying to export it to a higher quality / resolution and at this point it works
well but when I'm trying to manage rotation + position it isn't going well.

Export render :
[image: Export render]

I used chatGPT to help about rotation but I think he can't understand properly how to manage left and top properties.

If you have any question about the code answer me. ( I think the code speaks by itself but maybe it's because I'm on it since Tuesday )

There is my function that manage rotation :

````
// Props
        let self = this
        let highRes_canvas = []
        let mergedCanvas = null
        let resolution = {}

        if (format === '1-1')
            resolution = { width: 1920, height: 1920 }
        else if (format === '16-9')
            resolution = { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
        else if (format === '9-16')
            resolution = { width: 1080, height: 1920 }
        else
            resolution = { width: this.el_designer.offsetWidth, height: this.el_designer.offsetHeight }


        let ratio = resolution.width / this.el_designer.offsetWidth
        exportCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        exportCanvas.width = resolution.width
        exportCanvas.height = resolution.height
        let ctx = exportCanvas.getContext('2d')


        await loadImages() // Use promise to load all images of layers that had one

        // Manage layers array to manage layer as individual

        for (const layer of layers) {
            let top = parseFloat(layer.el.style.top) || 0;   // Layer.el is the original layer that need to be up to higher quality
            let left = parseFloat(layer.el.style.left) || 0; 
            let width = parseFloat(layer.el.width) * ratio;  
            let height = parseFloat(layer.el.height) * ratio;

            if (layer.type === 'image' || layer.type === 'shape') {
                if (layer.image) { // Layer.image contain the <img /> element 
                    ctx.save() // save context
                    layer.image.style.top  = top+'px'
                    layer.image.style.left = left+'px'
                     
                    // Calculate coords
                    const rotationCenterX = parseFloat(layer.image.style.transformOrigin.split(' ')[0]) * width
                    const rotationCenterY = parseFloat(layer.image.style.transformOrigin.split(' ')[1]) * height

                    // Translate
    
                    const translatedX = left * ratio
                    const translatedY = top * ratio

                    // Rotate
                    const rotationAngle = await getRotationAngle(layer.el.style.transform) // return angle in radians
                    ctx.translate(translatedX, translatedY)
    
                    ctx.rotate(rotationAngle)

                    // Draw
                    //ctx.drawImage(layer.image, 0, 0, width, height)
                    ctx.drawImage(layer.image, -width / 2, - height / 2)

                    ctx.restore(); // Restore
                }
            } else if (layer.type === "text") { 
                //...
            }```
````

Comment: You would probably have a better time if your app was working in a `<canvas>` all the time, not just for export. (It looks like you're currently using `<img>`s for the preview, right?)

Comment: @AKX Oh sorry I didn't explain a lot about the context so basically all images texts are canvasses but in the case of export I need to generate an image with another size and another resolution so I do it with <img > but maybe I'm totally wrong by doing this

Comment: But instead of having them be separate elements (`layer.image.style.transformOrigin` and all that), you could composite them onto a single canvas to begin with – then it should be a lot easier to just scale up that canvas when you're exporting.

Comment: (It's too bad that [`CSSTransformValue`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/cssom/#css-transform-values) is not supported in Firefox at all (and I assume you want to support Firefox); that would make it very easy to get a transform matrix from your layers.)

Comment: @AKX I’m using safari but I think it don’t work because I’m not doing el.appendChild(Mycanvas)